# Dompdf Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found

Tags: dompdf

Using Dompdf to generate a pdf file.  The file is created successfully and downloads but the page I'm running it on generates a fatal error - Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found.

I've downloaded the latest package and uploaded it to the server.

I'm using the quick start code from here - https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#easy-installation

```
require_once 'path/to/the/folder/here/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

I've read all the related support posts I can find but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just instantiate the dompdf class as follow: *$dompdf = new **\Dompdf\Dompdf()**;*

```
<?php
require_once 'path/to/the/folder/here/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    
// Instantiate and use the dompdf class, as follow:
$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();

// Then continue your code here...
```